# Amount of amplification required for a certain accuracy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, error-analysis

We want to measure the resistance of a resistor up to a certain accuracy. To this end, we use a fixed voltage and measure the current through a I/V converter. This measured voltage is then sent to an A/D converter with a certain input voltage range.

Now, what I'm puzzled about that the accuracy of our measurement can be affected by the amplification of our I/V converter. I would suspect that once we've set the I/V converter to the right amplification value, the accuracy would be completely determined by the resolution of our A/D converter.

For example, say we want to measure a resistance R using a voltage V. Our current would then be I = V/R. If we now want our measurement to be up to, say, 1 percent, what kind of implications does this have for the amount of amplification required of our I/V converter?

---

We want to choose the amplification A of our I/V converter such that $I \cdot A$ lies within the input voltage range of the A/D converter. What can we now say about the accuracy of the measurement? When is it within 1 percent accurate?

**The problem statement**

> We want to measure the resistance of a single atom ($R=12.9k\Omega$). We'll be using a voltage of $U=50mV$. A current-to-voltage converter (I/V-converter) is used to convert the measured current to a $10^x$ time higher voltage (1 Ampère is $10^x$ Volt). This voltage is then sent to a 16-bit A/D converter with an input range of $-5$ to $5V$.
>
> What should the value of $X$ be so that the resistance can be measured up to $1\%$ accuracy?
>
> 1. (A) $X$ must be at least $3$;
> 2. (B) $X$ must be at least $4$;
> 3. (C) $X$ must be at least $4$ and maximally $6$ or
> 4. (D) $X$ must be at least $3$ and maximally $7$

I don't understand how we can distinguish the difference in accuracy between the cases. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

---

Our current is given by $I=\frac{U}{R}= 3.6nA$. The resolution of our A/D converter is given by $\frac{5--5}{2^{16}-1} = 1.5\cdot10^{-4} V$.

Hence at an amplification of $10^3$ our signal would be picked up by our A/D converter, since this is within the resolution. At an amplification at 10^7 this is no longer the case, since $36V > 5V$.

This leads me to go for (C); $X$ must be at least $4$ and maximally $6$. I do not know, however, how to calculate the accuracy in each case. How would you determine the accuracy?

Comment: Without any idea of the noise sources (including the amplifiers), the question is useless in any practical sense. As a homework exercise, well, that runs afoul of the general homework policy. And the question is worded, well, horribly.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm pretty sure this question is getting at the quantization limit of the ADC. I agree that the question might bump up against the homework policy, but in fact a simple answer about quantization error and some editing of the OP woul make a nice tidy Q&A.

Comment: @DanielSank - you always want your input signal range to be as close as possible to the ADC full scale (except of course when noise kills you). This is not a particularly deep physics question. And, as many find out, noise sources are the real limiter. On the other hand, I know how to design and build a 4-pole Chebyshev band pass filter...

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not sure "deepness" is a prerequisite for posting on this site. Also, I'm not sure why you're explaining dynamic range to me in the comments instead of just answering OP's question. Also, I would note that ego-stroking doesn't help OP.

Comment: @JonCuster http://journal.sjdm.org/15/15923a/jdm15923a.pdf

Comment: @JonCuster I agree that you want to be as close to the ADC full scale as possible. Sure. Noise isn't considered in this textbook problem, it seems.

Comment: @DanielSank I would attribute the accuracy of this measurement completely to the quantization limit of the ADC, reading the problem statement. However, the choices imply that the amplification (of the I/V converter) is a parameter for the accuracy, which is what I don't understand.

Comment: @MusséRedi the amplifier is used to bring the signal up to a level that satisfies the ADC's dynamic range.

Comment: @DanielSank I think, I'm up to something. Enough hints for now. :)

Comment: @DanielSank The strange this is that the resolution of the ADC --- i.e. $\frac{5V--5V}{2^{16}-1}=0.15 mV$ --- stays the same, whatever the dynamic range might be. Hence, one would think that the *accuracy* also stays the same; because when you're measuring something, it's the resolution that determines what's measurable. In the case of (C), we have a dynamic range of $36mV$ up to $3.6V$. In the case of (D), we have a dynamic range of $3.6mV$ up to $5V$. Obviously, (D) has a better dynamic range; but that doesn't tell me anything about the difference in accuracy of between C and D.

Comment: @BernardoMeurer Btw, thanks for the link. It was a good read. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are important to note when we want to discuss whether a
measurement lies within a certain accuracy. Can we measure the value
that we want to measure, i.e. does our measurement value lie within
the dynamic range? Do we have enough resolution to resolve a measurement up to a certain
percentage of our measurement value?

Well, since we *know* our measurement value --- it is
$I=\frac{50mV}{12.9k\Omega} = 3.6nA$, the first question we need
to ask is: how much do we need to amplify this signal to measure it
properly?

This give rise to another question. Whether we can measure something
or not is determined by the *resolution* of our system. It is
$$\frac{U_{max}-U_{min}}{2^{bits}-1}=\frac{5V--5V}{2^{16}-1} = 1.5mV
\ .$$
Hence, our minimal amplication is given by $$\frac{0.15mV}{3.6nA} =
41.6 V/A \ .$$

Since our question is asking for an integer exponent $x$ of $10$, we need
$x>3$.

---

We now look into the accuracy requirement. If we want an accuracy of
$1\%$, this is equivalent to saying we want to be able to measure a
deviation of up to $1\%$ of our measurement value $R=12.9k\Omega$. Put
$\Delta R := 0.01 \cdot R = 129 \Omega$. In order to measure this we
need to measure a current of $\Delta I = \frac{50mV}{129\Omega} =
0.39mA$. This is accomplished even with the minimal amount of
amplification $10^3$, since this is solely determined by our ADC
resolution $0.15mV$ which is more that twice sufficient.

We conclude by remarking that at an amplification of $10^7$, our
measurement voltage value will be $36V$, which lies outside the range
of the input voltage of our ADC. Hence, we are left with the case of
(C), as the only viable option: $x$ must be at least $4$ and maximally
$6$.